# Simple file downloader

Tags: php

I am fairly new to php and have managed to string together this simple download script by reading some of the questions listed here at SO and would like to ask those of you that are more familiar with php to take a look at the code below and see if there are any glaring flaws with my implementation or anything that should be changed.

Just letting you know that the during my limited testing, everything seemed to work fine, but as I said I am fairly new to php and want to make sure I am not missing something that might break the script later down the road.

```
<?php

//Settings
$filesPath   = './files';
$fileName    = $_GET['file'];
$allowedExts = array('jpg','png','gif');


//Functions 
//Returns the extension portion of a filename.
function file_extension($fileName)
{
    $path_info = pathinfo($fileName);
    return strtolower($path_info['extension']);
}

//Validation and processing
//Check that a file is actually being requested
if (empty($fileName)) {
    die('no file was requested');
}

//Check that the file is allowed to be downloaded   
if (!in_array(file_extension($fileName), $allowedExts)) {
    die('you cannot download this file');
}

//Get the file  
if (file_exists($filesPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($fileName));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($fileName);
    exit;
}
?>
```

TIA,
Dave

Comment: Not security related but you should have `set_time_limit(0);` if you don't want your download to abort half way through at random.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Thanks, I added the setting, not sure my host will honor it tho.

Comment: Not as a setting, just in your php code, near the top, add `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/

Answer (score 3):

Your script may be vulnerable to directory traversal. In your case, I would use [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) on the filename and check that it is a valid file within `.files/`.

There is a possibility that someone can traverse up the directory tree and steal files such as `/etc/passwd` and so on.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that, but would the extension checking not stop them from accessing any files other then the ones that were in the allowedExt array ?

Comment: Just to update I tried traversing the url with something like this download.php?file=../../../../../etc/passwd and recieved a 403 forbidden error message so I am not sure how to test for this vulnerability.

Comment: It is possible that your webserver is set up with its own user account and is limited to access only certain directories or running SuPHP. However, It is still good practice to do checks like this in case the script is executed in a badly configured server

Comment: In regards to checking the extension, that is not enough as attackers can use a NULL byte to "skip" the extension. See this page for more details: http://www.madirish.net/node/427

Comment: Thanks again for the replies and information. I will definitely read all of the material that you presented. I seem to be having problems with large files not downloading or just downloading a few bytes then stopping so I will will have to look into that as well. Thx again for the info tho, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are open to hackers attacks, someone could just do ?file=../etc/passwd/ and bam owned
you better do some checks on how to protect against lfi